# Go concurrency with rate limit for API Calls?

Tags: go, concurrency, semaphore, channel, rate

I am trying to make concurrent HTTP post call to telnyx(message service) API and then update database with the respose. The API has a limit on max call of 200/s for us.Below is the code i came up with after reseaching.It works for small sample test. If somebody can explain if this approach is correct and can deal with large number of calls in production down the line and if i am using the rate,channel and waitgroup correctly in Send()?

```
func SMSPost(m Message) (*http.Response, error) {
....
return response,nil
}

func Send(sendmessage []Message,db *sql.DB){
    rlim := rate.NewLimiter(200, 200)

    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, 20)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < len(sendmessages); i++ {
        
        sendmessage := sendmessages[i]
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            err := rlim.Wait(context.Background())
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("rate Wait:", err)
                
            }

            // Check the concurrency semaphore.
            semaphore <- struct{}{}
            defer func() { <-semaphore }()

            
            response, err := SMSPost(sendmessage)

          /*
       ...Inserting/updating multiple database table based on response
          */

      }()
   }
wg.wait()
}
```

Comment: The `semaphore` seems to limit the active goroutines to 20. Why not create a fixed number of goroutines, and feed the messages to them through a channel, instead of creating many and making others wait?

Comment: @Burak.. Thats one of the thing i was't clear about how to use efficiently. Should i extend semaphore to 200 goroutines, since the limit for me is 200 http/s or it be best to create some number of gorutines like you mentioned. Not sure about the pros and cons here.

Comment: Functionally the two approaches are the same. I'd do it using a fixed number of goroutines. One potential problem would he the fact that you'd have a potentially unbounded number of goroutines of which only a small number running actively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your approach with the semaphorcounter. But try and check before you create the goroutine or else you will create an unlimited number of routines and then wait inside the routine.
So just push the 'semaphore <- struct{}{}' up, before you create the goroutine and then you only have a limited number of goroutines at one time:

```
for i := 0; i < len(sendmessages); i++ {
    
    sendmessage := sendmessages[i]
    wg.Add(1)
    // Check the concurrency semaphore.
    semaphore <- struct{}{}
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := rlim.Wait(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("rate Wait:", err)
            
        }

        defer func() { <-semaphore }()

        
        response, err := SMSPost(sendmessage)

      /*
   ...Inserting/updating multiple database table based on response
      */

  }()
```

}